# Searching a sequence in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, search

Let's say I have the following array :

```
 array([2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

How do I get the indices where I have occurrence of sequence of values : `[0,0]`? So, the expected output for such a case would be : `[1,2,6,7]`.

**Edit :**

1) Please note that `[0,0]` is just a sequence. It could be `[0,0,0]` or `[4,6,8,9]` or `[5,2,0]`, just anything.

2) If my array were modified to : `array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])`, the expected result with the same sequence of `[0,0]` would be `[1,2,3,4,8,9]`.

I am looking for some NumPy shortcut.

Comment: what about `array([2, 0, 0,0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])`?

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you want a generic method that would accommodate for any sequence, with [0, 0] just being an example?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, this is basically a [`template-matching problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) that comes up in image-processing a lot. Listed in this post are two approaches: Pure NumPy based and OpenCV (cv2) based.

**Approach #1:** With NumPy, one can create a `2D` array of sliding indices across the entire length of the input array. Thus, each row would be a sliding window of elements. Next, match up each row with the input sequence, which will bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution. We look for all `True` rows indicating those are the ones that are the perfect matches and as such would be the starting indices of the matches. Finally, using those indices, create a range of indices extending up to the length of the sequence, to give us the desired output. The implementation would be -

```
def search_sequence_numpy(arr,seq):
    """ Find sequence in an array using NumPy only.

    Parameters
    ----------    
    arr    : input 1D array
    seq    : input 1D array

    Output
    ------    
    Output : 1D Array of indices in the input array that satisfy the 
    matching of input sequence in the input array.
    In case of no match, an empty list is returned.
    """

    # Store sizes of input array and sequence
    Na, Nseq = arr.size, seq.size

    # Range of sequence
    r_seq = np.arange(Nseq)

    # Create a 2D array of sliding indices across the entire length of input array.
    # Match up with the input sequence & get the matching starting indices.
    M = (arr[np.arange(Na-Nseq+1)[:,None] + r_seq] == seq).all(1)

    # Get the range of those indices as final output
    if M.any() >0:
        return np.where(np.convolve(M,np.ones((Nseq),dtype=int))>0)[0]
    else:
        return []         # No match found
```

**Approach #2:** With OpenCV (cv2), we have a built-in function for `template-matching` : [`cv2.matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#cv.MatchTemplate). Using this, we would have the starting matching indices. Rest of the steps would be same as for the previous approach. Here's the implementation with `cv2` :

```
from cv2 import matchTemplate as cv2m

def search_sequence_cv2(arr,seq):
    """ Find sequence in an array using cv2.
    """

    # Run a template match with input sequence as the template across
    # the entire length of the input array and get scores.
    S = cv2m(arr.astype('uint8'),seq.astype('uint8'),cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

    # Now, with floating point array cases, the matching scores might not be 
    # exactly zeros, but would be very small numbers as compared to others.
    # So, for that use a very small to be used to threshold the scorees 
    # against and decide for matches.
    thresh = 1e-5 # Would depend on elements in seq. So, be careful setting this.

    # Find the matching indices
    idx = np.where(S.ravel() < thresh)[0]

    # Get the range of those indices as final output
    if len(idx)>0:
        return np.unique((idx[:,None] + np.arange(seq.size)).ravel())
    else:
        return []         # No match found
```

---

**Sample run**

```
In [512]: arr = np.array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])

In [513]: seq = np.array([0,0])

In [514]: search_sequence_numpy(arr,seq)
Out[514]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9])

In [515]: search_sequence_cv2(arr,seq)
Out[515]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9])
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [477]: arr = np.random.randint(0,9,(100000))
     ...: seq = np.array([3,6,8,4])
     ...: 

In [478]: np.allclose(search_sequence_numpy(arr,seq),search_sequence_cv2(arr,seq))
Out[478]: True

In [479]: %timeit search_sequence_numpy(arr,seq)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ms per loop

In [480]: %timeit search_sequence_cv2(arr,seq)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop
```

Seems like the Pure NumPy based one is the safest and fastest!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Divakar's solution for quite a while, and it is working perfectly. Thank you very much! However, a couple of days ago, I needed something faster for a certain project. Using strides https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html  saves a lot of memory since it creates a "fake copy", and numexpr https://github.com/pydata/numexpr is about twice as fast as numpy, but even without numexpr it is pretty fast

```
import numexpr
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, window):
    """
    Generate a rolling window view of a 1-dimensional NumPy array.

    Parameters:
    a (numpy.ndarray): The input array.
    window (int): The size of the rolling window.

    Returns:
    numpy.ndarray: A view of the input array with shape (N - window + 1, window), where N is the size of the input array.

    Example:
    >>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    >>> windowed = rolling_window(a, 3)
    >>> print(windowed)
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 3, 4],
           [3, 4, 5]])
    """

    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)


def circular_rolling_window(a, window):
    """
    Generate a circular rolling window view of a 1-dimensional NumPy array.

    Parameters:
    a (numpy.ndarray): The input array.
    window (int): The size of the circular rolling window.

    Returns:
    numpy.ndarray: A view of the input array with shape (N, window), where N is the size of the input array, and the window wraps around at the boundaries.

    Example:
    >>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    >>> circular_windowed = circular_rolling_window(a, 3)
    >>> print(circular_windowed)
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 3, 4],
           [3, 4, 5],
           [4, 5, 1],
           [5, 1, 2]])
    """

    pseudocircular = np.pad(a, pad_width=(0, window - 1), mode="wrap")
    return rolling_window(pseudocircular, window)


def find_sequence_in_array(sequence, array, numexpr_enabled=True):
    """
    Find occurrences of a sequence in a 1-dimensional NumPy array using a rolling window approach.

    Parameters:
    sequence (numpy.ndarray): The sequence to search for.
    array (numpy.ndarray): The input array to search within.
    numexpr_enabled (bool, optional): Whether to use NumExpr for efficient computation (default is True).

    Returns:
    numpy.ndarray: An array of indices where the sequence is found in the input array.

    Example:
    >>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    >>> seq = np.array([3, 4, 5])
    >>> indices = find_sequence_in_array(seq, arr)
    >>> print(indices)
    [2 7]
    """

    a3 = circular_rolling_window(array, len(sequence))
    if numexpr_enabled:
        isseq = numexpr.evaluate(
            "a3==sequence", global_dict={}, local_dict={"a3": a3, "sequence": sequence}
        )
        su1 = numexpr.evaluate(
            "sum(isseq,1)", global_dict={}, local_dict={"isseq": isseq.astype(np.int8)}
        )
        wherelen = numexpr.evaluate(
            "(su1==l)", global_dict={}, local_dict={"su1": su1, "l": len(sequence)}
        )
    else:
        isseq = a3 == sequence
        su1 = np.sum(isseq, axis=1)
        wherelen = su1 == len(sequence)

    resu = np.nonzero(wherelen)
    return resu[0]
seq = np.array([3, 6, 8, 4])
arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (100000,))
%timeit a3 = find_sequence_in_array(sequence=seq, array=arr, numexpr_enabled=True)
1.32 ms ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit a3 = find_sequence_in_array(sequence=seq, array=arr, numexpr_enabled=False)
2.2 ms ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit a4 = search_sequence_numpy(arr=arr, seq=seq)
4.96 ms ± 50.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a NumPy one-liner that is much faster than the others

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

def np_search_sequence(a, seq, distance=1):
    return np.where(reduce(lambda a,b:a & b, ((np.concatenate([(a == s)[i * distance:], np.zeros(i * distance, dtype=np.uint8)],dtype=np.uint8)) for i,s in enumerate(seq))))[0]
seq = np.array([3, 6, 8, 4])
arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (100000,))
%timeit np_search_sequence(a=arr, seq=seq, distance=1)
604 µs ± 7.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

**Input Parameters:**

a: NumPy array in which the search is performed.

seq: Sequence to search for within the array.

distance: Minimum distance between consecutive elements of the sequence in the array (default is 1)
You can use distance 2 when looking for utf-8 strings in e.g. memory dumps

**Using reduce and lambda function:**

The reduce function is employed with a lambda function to iteratively perform a bitwise AND (&) operation on the binary arrays.

**Sequence Processing:**

For each element s in the given sequence (seq), the code does the following:
Creates a binary array indicating the presence of the current element at the desired distance
in the array ((a == s)[i * distance:]).
Appends a binary array of zeros (np.zeros(i * distance, dtype=np.uint8))
to ensure alignment with the original array.

**Final Result:**

Obtains the indices where the boolean array is True using np.where.
Returns these indices as a NumPy array.

Comment: Nice solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the most succinct, intuitive and general way to do this is using regular expressions.

```
import re
import numpy as np

# Set the threshold for string printing to infinite
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)

# Remove spaces and linebreaks that would come through when printing your vector
yourarray_string = re.sub('\n|\s','',np.array_str( yourarray ))[1:-1]

# The next line is the most important, set the arguments in the braces
# such that the first argument is the shortest sequence you want
# and the second argument is the longest (using empty as infinite length)

r = re.compile(r"[0]{1,}") 
zero_starts = [m.start() for m in r.finditer( yourarray_string )]
zero_ends = [m.end() for m in r.finditer( yourarray_string )]
```

Comment: Converting number sequence into string? Replacing nicely packed fixed length (in bytes) array of numbers with variable length strings?