# Replace a zero sequence with other value

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a big dataset (> 200k) and I am trying to replace zero sequences with a value. A zero sequence with more than 2 zeros is an artifact and should be removed by setting it to np.NAN.

I have read [Searching a sequence in a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522220/searching-a-sequence-in-a-numpy-array) but it did not fully match my requirement, as i do not have static pattern.

```
np.array([0, 1.0, 0, 0, -6.0, 13.0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 16.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
# should be converted to this
np.array([0, 1.0, 0, 0, -6.0, 13.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.0, 16.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
```

If you need some more information, let me know.
Thanks in advance!

---

Results:

Thanks for the answers, here are my (unprofessional) test results running on 288240 points

```
divakar took 0.016000ms to replace 87912 points
desiato took 0.076000ms to replace 87912 points
polarise took 0.102000ms to replace 87912 points
```

As @Divakar's solution is the shortest and fastest I accept his one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's basically a [`binary closing operation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_closing.html) with a threshold requirement on the closing gap. Here's an implementation based on it -

```
# Pad with ones so as to make binary closing work around the boundaries too
a_extm = np.hstack((True,a!=0,True))

# Perform binary closing and look for the ones that have not changed indiicating
# the gaps in those cases were above the threshold requirement for closing
mask = a_extm == binary_closing(a_extm,structure=np.ones(3))

# Out of those avoid the 1s from the original array and set rest as NaNs
out = np.where(~a_extm[1:-1] & mask[1:-1],np.nan,a)
```

---

One way to avoid that appending in the earlier method as needed to work with boundary elements, which might make it a bit expensive when dealing with large dataset, would be like so -

```
# Create binary closed mask
mask = ~binary_closing(a!=0,structure=np.ones(3))
idx = np.where(a)[0]
mask[:idx[0]] = idx[0]>=3
mask[idx[-1]+1:] = a.size - idx[-1] -1 >=3

# Use the mask to set NaNs in a
out = np.where(mask,np.nan,a)
```

Comment: @ppasler Would you be kind enough to let us know how the listed approaches work on your large dataset (>200K) in terms of runtime?

Comment: Sure, see the results after the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can use for your lists:

```
import numpy as np

def replace(a_list):
    for i in xrange(len(a_list) - 2):
        print a_list[i:i+3]
        if (a_list[i] == 0 and a_list[i+1] == 0 and a_list[i+2] == 0) or (a_list[i] is np.NaN and a_list[i+1] is np.NaN and a_list[i+2] == 0):
            a_list[i] = np.NaN
            a_list[i+1] = np.NaN
            a_list[i+2] = np.NaN
    return a_list
```

Because the list is traversed in one direction you only have two comparisons: `(0, 0, 0)` or `(NaN, NaN, 0)` because you replace `0` with `NaN` as you go.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I get a `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` in line `data[i] = np.NaN`

Comment: Are you applying this to a list or to an `np.array`? I think you should use it like so: `np.array(replace(the_list))`...

Answer (score 1):

you could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

l = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, -6, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0])

def _ret_list( k, it ):
    # number of elements in iterator, i.e., length of list of similar items
    l = sum( 1 for i in it )

    if k==0 and l>2:
        # sublist has more than two zeros. replace each zero by np.nan
        return [ np.nan ]*l
    else:
        # return sublist of simliar items
        return [ k ]*l

# group items and apply _ret_list on each group
procesed_l = [_ret_list(k,g) for k,g in groupby(l)]
# flatten the list and convert to a numpy array
procesed_l = np.array( [ item for l in procesed_l for item in l ] )

print procesed_l
```

which gives you

```
[  0.   1.   0.   0.  -6.  13.  nan  nan  nan   1.  16.  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

note that each `int` are converted to a `float`. see here: [NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value)

Comment: Works great - thanks! I prefere @Divakar solution, as it is a bit shorter.

Comment: Just figured out, that every sequence with the same numbers is replaced: `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0]` leads to `[NaN, Nan, NaN, NaN, 0]`

Comment: ah, yes. I've corrected my answer by adding another condition to if statement