# Find and replace subarray in python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, noise-reduction

I have a 6600X5100 numpy array which represents a black & white image.
I want to clear this image from black pixels noise- remove all black pixle lines (vertically and horizontally) that are shorter than 2 pixels.

So if I have something like this:

```
[0,  0,  0,   0,   0, 255]
[0, 255,255, 255, 255, 0 ]
[0, 255,255, 255,  0,  0 ]
[0, 255,255 ,255,  0, 255]
[0, 255,255, 255,  0, 255]
[0,  0,  0,   0,   0,  0 ]
```

The output array will be like this:

```
[0,  0,  0,   0,   0,  0 ]
[0, 255,255, 255,  0 , 0 ]
[0, 255,255, 255,  0,  0 ]
[0, 255,255 ,255,  0,  0 ]
[0, 255,255, 255,  0,  0 ]
[0,  0,  0,   0,   0,  0 ]
```

Performance is critical here so a simple loop over the array won't do.
Is there a way to quickly find and replace subarray inside an array?
So if [0, 255, 255, 0] or [0, 255, 0] is in the image array, replace those parts with 0.

Or if you have a better solution for this task, I will be grateful.

Comment: Is using [`scikit`](http://scikit-image.org/) or [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) functions acceptable?

Comment: `scikit` is fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching a sequence in a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522220/searching-a-sequence-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at the morphological filters of scikit-image.

You can define simple filters and use the `opening` function to clean up the image.  You will have to play with the filters to get them exactly as you need them, but the library is very fast.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import opening

img = np.array([[0,  0,  0,   0,   0, 255],
                [0, 255,255, 255, 255, 0 ],
                [0, 255,255, 255,  0,  0 ],
                [0, 255,255 ,255,  0, 255],
                [0, 255,255, 255,  0, 255],
                [0,  0,  0,   0,   0,  0 ]])


# horizontal and vertical filters
hf = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,1,1,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0]])
vf = hf.T

# apply each filter in turn
out = opening(opening(img, hf),vf)

out
# returns:
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I used it with 'closing' instead of 'opening' since 255 represents white in my image.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to the existing one, but I use 2d-convolutions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

in_arr = np.array([
    [0,  0,  0,   0,   0, 255],
    [0, 255,255, 255, 255, 0 ],
    [0, 255,255, 255,  0,  0 ],
    [0, 255,255 ,255,  0, 255],
    [0, 255,255, 255,  0, 255],
    [0,  0,  0,   0,   0,  0 ]])

padded = np.pad(in_arr, 1, mode='constant', constant_values=0)

# Create a kernel
kern = np.ones((1, 3))

# Perform convolution
mask = np.logical_and((conv2(in_arr, kern,   mode='same') // 255) >= 2,
                      (conv2(in_arr, kern.T, mode='same') // 255) >= 2)

# Apply mask:
out_arr = in_arr * mask
```

Which also yields the desired result.

Comment: Really interesting solution!